# How to disable spell checking in Atom?

Tags: plugins, spell-check, atom-editor

I would like to turn off spell checking in Atom in one file. I cannot find any shortcut or option for that.

When I open a file with some non-programming stuff I get a red flood from the spell checker.

[image: Text with many words underlined as typos.]

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it covers most of the things you might want to do with the `spell-check` plugin: http://superuser.com/a/1003636/442991

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P, type "spell", select the option "Spell Check: Toggle". Unfortunately Atom doesn't remember this an after reopening Atom or even after saving the file, it's enabled again...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Disable the spell-check plugin

1. Go to **Settings** > **Packages** > **Spell Check**.
2. Click the **Disable** button.
   [image: Disable]

---

### Toggle spell check for the current file

1. Open up the **Command Pallette** (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).
2. Type in `Spell Check: Toggle`.
3. Hit enter.

---

### Create a shortcut to toggle spell checking

1. Go to **Atom** > **Keymap..**.
2. Add those lines at the bottom of the `keymap.cson` file:

   ```
   'atom-text-editor':
     'cmd-alt-s': 'spell-check:toggle'
   ```
3. Restart Atom.

---

### Disable spell check for certain file types

There is a default list of scopes which triggers spell checking. You have to define your own list if you want to modify it.

1. Go to **Settings** > **Packages** > **Spell Check**.
2. Enter your modified list of scopes into the **Settings** > **Grammars**.
   [image: Spell Check package settings]

#### How to define my own list of scopes?

The default list of scopes includes: `source.asciidoc`, `source.gfm`, `text.git-commit`, `text.plain`, `text.plain.null-grammar`

If you don't know which scope applies to your currently opened file:

1. Open up the **Command Pallette** (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).
2. Type in `Editor: Log Cursor Scope`.
3. Hit enter.
4. A notification like this should pop up:
   [image: notification]
5. The first item on the list is the scope which applies to your file.

---

#### Further reading

You can read more on the GitHub page of this package: https://github.com/atom/spell-check#spell-check-package.

Comment: brilliant answer

Answer (score 61):

## Disable spell checking in Atom

For temporary solution or for someone like me permanent solution:

1. go to "File / Settings / Packages"
2. search "spell-check"
3. click to button "Disable"

Comment: As of today, Atom spell check is still buggy and doesn't save between sessions. Disabling the package does work.

Answer (score 6):

#### I would like to turn off spell checking in Atom in one file

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/atom/spell-check/pull/33) (Add feature: toggle on/off) for this:

> I added the feature 'Toggle' to the 'Packages -> Spell Check' menu.

Update 08/01/2016:

> All checks have passed
>
> 1 successful check
>
> This branch has no conflicts with the base branch
>
> Only those with write access to this repository can merge pull requests.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to open a very large non-English file, and the spell checker caused Atom to completely freeze. Worse, even after I kill Atom and try to relaunch it, it tries to open the same file immediately.

Eventually I had to run `apm disable spell-check` in the command line. This is the solution when you can't even launch Atom.

Comment: thank you for the solution to these kind of issues!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `spell-check` plugin itself is not recommended. Instead you should remove that cursor scope from included ones in `spell-check` plugin.

**Steps for removing cursor scope from `spell-check`**:

1. Open the file that you want to be excluded from spell check.
2. Open command pallete (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`) and run the `Editor: Log Cursor Scope` command. This will trigger a notification which will contain a list of scopes.
3. Remove the scopes listed in the pop up from `spell-check` included scopes in settings. Included scopes can be found in Grammers section of `spell-check` settings(**Settings > Packages > Spell Check > Grammers**).

This should disable spell check for that particular kind of file only.